# Trouble with simplexml_load_string in PHP with Soap response

Tags: php, simplexml

- few edits*

I'm using SoapClient to work with a Web Service which results with a sequence of anyTypes. I have tried to use simplexml_load_string on the response (possibly wrongly) and it fails resulting in simplexml_load_string not being set.

That aside, my PHP code that calls the web service: (no problem here)

```
$client->InvokeWorkflow( $params );
```

I then catch the response as $response:

$response = $client->__getLastResponse();

When I var_dump $response I get:

```
string(1404) "XmlOut<Organisations xmlns="http://www.XXXXXXXX.net/Schemas/Provision/Organisations.xsd"><Organisation xmlns="http://www.XXXXXXXX.net/Schemas/Provision/Organisations.xsd"><DomainName>XXXXXXXXX.co.za</DomainName><Action>Suspend</Action><ActionType>Organisation</ActionType><InternalReference>1234</InternalReference><StatusInfo><Status>Error</Status><Error><Field> (Validate 1.0.0.0): DomainName</Field><ErrorMessage>The domain is already suspended</ErrorMessage></Error></StatusInfo></Organisation></Organisations>statustruestatusMessagetaskStartIda0c5ce73-1915-4695-a50c-f05b431f8a14"
```

You will notice an XmlOut followed by XML string, followed by some text starting with statustruestatusMessage.

That response is actually a set of anyTypes. The first is "XmlOut", the second is all of the XML looking string, followed by "status", "true", "statusMessage", "", "taskStartId", "0c5ce73-1915-4695-a50c-f05b431f8a14"

I'm trying to get the values for:

- ErrorMessage (which is "The domain is already suspended")
- Status (which is true in the above example)

Comment: You should put the code you're using back up. I can't remember what it was. That string is definitely invalid XML which is why simplexml_load_string is returning false (which is what it does when it fails)

Comment: Will do. Just got to the office.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using PHP's SoapClient class, you don't need to/can't  load the response as a string.

Simply use the $response variable. It's already a PHP object.

try

```
var_dump($response);
```